# Is this hadith about the night prayer authentic?

Tags: hadith, sahih-bukhari, sahih-muslim

Does anybody know this hadith at [this youtube short video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/m-GZKSrMVgc?feature=share)?

If so, can you tell us reference to this hadith and whether it is authentic?

Comment: Please properly elaborate your question, and mention the text or meaning of the hadith in the text of your post. It is lazy to expect others to watch a video from another site, and that too in another language, before they can understand what you want. The hadith is from Abu Dawud: https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1398